# IntelliJ WebStorm + Angular ng-serve autosave on every character type

Tags: angular, angular-cli, webstorm, intellij-14

I'm facing an annoying "feature"... Every time I am writing the code in the WebStorm and ng serve runs it starts to compile for every character I type.

I tried to find out how to disable or at least delay this function but I couldn't find anything.

---

`WebStorm -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Synchronization` 
every option is disabled.

What settings or option I am missing? I would like to keep the live reload but only with manual saving or at least some delay.

Comment: try Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript -> Uncheck 'Recompile on changes'

Comment: does it only happen during debugging? Do you have Live edit enabled (*Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Live Edit, Update application in Chrome*)? It auto-saves files to provide live reload

Comment: Live Edit disabled and now I also disabled Recompile on changes but it is still compiling on every char hit.

Comment: Do you have file watcher for prettier or tslit? i disable it and now seems okay